# "site" in "full site" is not correctly aligned

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

When the mobile version of a non-meta SE site is opened in portrait mode, the option to shift to "full site" is not correctly aligned with the word "site" being in the centre of the next line.

[image]

However, no such problem exists in a meta site (including this one).

[image]

This seems because of there being "too many" links at the bottom of the mobile version of a non-meta site compared to that of a meta site - a non-meta site has a link for "meta" as well.

Comment: Looks fine for me on a Pixel 3a with Android 10. What type of device do you have?

Comment: @Mark I have moto g6 with Android 9.

Comment: Reproduced on Huawei P20 Pro

Comment: it is likely due to the text being too long to fit in one single line. The word 'meta' must be the one that causes the overflow

Comment: The best solution here is to put a nbsp in “full site” and other two word options. On my screen (iPhone SE), there is no way for it to all fit on one line, so it should be allowed to spill over to the next line.

Comment: @fedorqui that is what I thought as well, and that's why thought of posting a pic of meta as well.